# Virtual private databases with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to have variable number databases that appear to be separate but are actually in one MySQL database.

These separate instances should be creatable and destroyable inside the application and while normal users work inside a single database instance, the system administrator could see all of them.

This concept seems similar to Oracle's Virtual Private Databases.

I am willing to implement the functionality in Laravel app but I am not sure how to do it.

I would add column `instance_id` to tables that I want to be instanced and the plain way would be to include something like `where('instance_id', Auth::user()->instance_id)` in every query, but this is nightmare to add that to every query...

How can I hide that in a neat way so I could either `use` something or `extend` improved model class whenever I need a model to be instanced. I want to do it in a way that I could also query the whole table ignoring instancing if I specify that.

Comment: Since there is no native support for what you want to do in mysql, the question is: is it easier to differenciate between user's data in a where clause (assuming that the data structure is the same for each user) or in the from clause.

Comment: @Shadow, sorry, what do you mean by "from clause"? To separate the data in different tables? That would mean I have to allow users to create/drop tables whenever a new project is created/deleted...

Comment: you have 2 options to separate data of users: use the same table, but add user id to each record or use different tables. In case of the latter, you need to distinguish between the various tables in the from clause.